# I'm trying to Implement TSP using recursive Topdown DP in java. The logic is correct but the answer differs

Tags: java, dynamic-programming

Trying with Travelling Salesman problem using dynamic programming. The code is error free but the output is not the one it should be. I have observed that the recursively returned answers are not getting added up to **newAns**, strange enough for me to understand. 
Any help into this part would be much appreciated.

```
public class TravellingSalesman {
    int ans = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    static int[][] dp = new int[16][4];

    int tsp(int[][] graph, int n, int mask, int pos){
        int Visited_All = (1 << n) - 1;
        if (mask == Visited_All)
            return  graph[pos][0];
        if(dp[mask][pos]!=-1)
            return dp[mask][pos];
        // unvisited cities
        for(int city = 0; city < n; city++){

             if ((mask & (1<<city)) == 0){
                 int newAns = 0;
                 newAns += (graph[pos][city] + tsp( graph,n,mask|(1<<city), city));
                ans = Math.min(ans, newAns);
            }
        }
        return  dp[mask][pos] = ans;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] graph =
                {
                        {0,20,42,25},
                        {20,0,30,34},
                        {42,30,0,10},
                        {25,34,10,0}
                };
        int n = 4;
        for(int i=0; i<(1<<n); i++){
            for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
                dp[i][j] = -1;
            }
        }
        TravellingSalesman ts = new TravellingSalesman();

        System.out.println(ts.tsp(graph,n,1,0));
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like that `newAns` has not a global scope, each time `tsp()` is called is set to `0`, maybe it needs to be defined outside the recurring functon...